# Twilio: Is there a way to update multiple conference participants at once?

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-conference

I would like to provide a button which mutes all conference participants who aren't moderators. The Twilio docs only show how to mute participants one at a time, each with a separate call to the Twilio API. Is there a way to batch these update requests, supplying multiple call SIDs? I'm using the Node JS library on Firebase Functions.

I thought that updating by participants' labels (e.g. "moderator", "attendee") would be the solution, but each participant's label must be unique.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Muting one at a time is the correct way to do this.

[Conference Participant Resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference-participant-resource)

Examples: "Mute Participant" and "Mute Participant by Label"

It looks like on way is, "Read multiple Participant resources" for your conference SID, and then once you have that result, loop through each participant and if their label is undefined, mute them. Anyone with a label would be a moderator.

Comment: Bit of a bummer that this requires potentially dozens of API calls instead of just one. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to terminate the conference (via the API), which makes each call continue down the TwiML path which can redirect to a page which will join callers to a new conference with muting disabled. Though the point at which unmuting the calls one-by-one becomes cumbersome is probably also the point at which you don't want to unmute all the calls (imagine 200+ calls in a conference, all unmuted!).